# How to convert a truth table to boolean expression?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

If I have a huge truth table, it's hard for me to construct an expression. I know a problematic method, the Disjunctive Normal Form. But I found that I cannot reduce the huge expression.

\begin{array}{c | c | c | c || c}
  \hline
        p & q & r & s & \phi \\ \hline
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 1):

You should look up [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)

With karnaugh maps you can turn any truth table into a minimally complex expression without too much brain power.
I would have put this in a comment but I can't comment yet.

Comment: I am not sure whether it still works, but a workaround (more of a bug) which enables new users to comment we [described here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9203/how-to-make-a-remark-when-reputation-is-under-50/13827#13827). (On the other hand, I am not sure whether what you posted is better as an answer or as a comment.)

Comment: "With karnaugh maps you can turn any truth table into a minimally complex expression without too much brain power."

What if you have 8 or 12 variables?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** when trying to simplify the disjunctive normal form for this expression, it may be helpful to use the absorption law. That is, for propositions $a$ and $b$:

> $a \vee (a\wedge b) \equiv a$.

The intuition behind this law is fairly obvious, if $a$ *and* $b$ has a truth value, then of course $a$ alone has the same truth value. So there would be a redundancy in saying the left side when it suffices to say just $a$.

You may try to apply this same reasoning to something like $a \vee (a\wedge b \wedge c)$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Whenever $p$ and $r$ are both true ($1$), the expression is false ($0$).  Can you say something similar about $q$ and $s$.